# Firebase realtime database doesn't set value - Android

Tags: java, firebase, google-maps, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating an app which shows the location of the users using that app so, I tried setting the location value in the realtime database using firebase but Firebase doesn't set the value at all and there is no error in the logcat either.

here's the code:

```
private fun getLastLocation() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        givePermission()
    }
    else{
        fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation
                .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->

                    //reference to the database
                    val database= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                    val ref: DatabaseReference = database.getReference("test")

                    if (task.isSuccessful && task.result != null) {
                        val mLastLocation = task.result

                        //location details must be stored in the realtime db 
                        ref.setValue(mLastLocation)

                        var address = "No known address"

                        val gcd = Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault())
                        val addresses: List<Address>
                        try {
                            addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(mLastLocation!!.latitude, mLastLocation.longitude, 1)
                            if (addresses.isNotEmpty()) {
                                address = addresses[0].getAddressLine(0)
                            }
                        } catch (e: IOException) {
                            e.printStackTrace()
                        }

                        val height = 100
                        val width = 100
                        val bitmapdraw: BitmapDrawable = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_pickup) as BitmapDrawable
                        val b: Bitmap = bitmapdraw.bitmap
                        val smallMarker: Bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, width, height, false)
                        

                        googleMap.addMarker(
                                MarkerOptions()
                                        .position(LatLng(mLastLocation!!.latitude, mLastLocation.longitude))
                                        .title("Current Location")
                                        .snippet(address)
                                       
                        )

                        val cameraPosition = CameraPosition.Builder()
                                .target(LatLng(mLastLocation.latitude, mLastLocation.longitude))
                                .zoom(25f)
                                .build()
                        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition))
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "No current location found. Please check your internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }
                }
    }
}
```

I want to store the location details of the user in the realtime database but it doesn't seem to work for some reason. Please help.
Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to attach a listener to the setValue operation? Are you getting some errors  there?

Comment: I added an addOnSuccessListener and made a toast if it was successful and when I run the app, I didn't see any toast getting displayed and no, I don't see any errors in the logcat

Comment: Is your onSucces or onFailure even triggered?

Comment: Not at all! It's like android studio doesn't see those lines of code. As if it's invisible to it

Comment: What is your database location?

Comment: Database location: Singapore (asia-southeast1). I live in Asia

Comment: Please check the duplicate to see how you can solve that issue.

Comment: Good to hear that. You're very welcome, perpetualdarkness!